# How to run Application on WatchKit Extension

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, watchkit

i create app which share data between iPhone to iWatch using [MMWormhole](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMWormhole)
first or second time when i run app it working. after it show me like

[image: See image]

I don't what happen. And also i don't change in Code.

Can anyone give me detail what is this. why is show.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: rewrite your question please. what I got: the issue is that after two successful runs the simulator won't start your app the third time?

Comment: @Daij-Djan yes. But so many time try it run app some time it run some time not. i think Apple watch simulator stuck  some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to stop and rerun your code twice times. Some time the application on Apple watch simulator stuck.